# AdWords Scope: gapi.client.adwords missing after authenticating with OAuth flow. Cannot find path variable to pass to gapi.client.request()

Tags: javascript, google-oauth, google-ads-api

I followed [this guide](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2UserAgent) to create a web app flow for authenticating users with Google.

Despite listing `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/adwords` in the scope parameter, I don't get a `gapi.client.adwords` or anything like that once the authentication is complete. *I am unable to retrieve any information about the user's MCC/AdWords/Ad Manager accounts.*

I've tried using `gapi.client.request()` but I can't seem to find the arguments that I should pass for access to the AdWords API.

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
let __req = gapi.client.request({
  method: "GET",
  path: "/adwords/v?/???",
  params: { fields: "???" }
});

__req.execute(function(response) {
  console.log(response);
});
```

... or like this:

```
console.log(gapi.client.adwords)
```

but I can't figure out what I need to pass to `gapi.client.request` and `gapi.client.adwords` doesn't exist.

Is it possible that I'm not passing a `discoveryDoc` or something like that? Where *is* the `discoveryDoc` for AdWords?

```
scope:
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/adwords",
discoveryDocs: ["???"]
```

Use Case: I'm trying to get a list of MCC/AdWords/Ad Manager accounts (specifically their ID's and names) that are associated with (or owned by) the authenticated user.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you can set DISCOVERY_DOCS to "https://googleads.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v11" and then you'll have `gapi.client.googleads`. However, it'll still complain about not having `developer-token`, which I'm trying to solve now, it seems to work if I copy request from dev tools and just add developer-token to it, perhaps you can do this with service worker

Comment: figured out how to use with `.request()`, here's a demo: https://github.com/Maxim-Mazurok/google-tasks-api-ts-example/tree/googleads

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Google Ads / Adwords API is pretty different from many other Google interfaces in that it isn't open to the general public and can't be accessed with the "normal" [API client libraries](https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client).

In order to interact with the Ads API (same goes for the older Adwords API) and access production accounts, you are required to present a valid developer token. To obtain one, you'll need to sign up for access as [described here](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/first-call/dev-token). Note that you'll get a developer token immediately, but you will only be able to access [test accounts](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/first-call/overview#test_account) until your application has been verified.

Once you have a developer token, it's recommended to use the official client libraries:

- [Ads API client libraries](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/client-libs) (REST-based, currently in Beta, will supersede the Adwords API going forward)
- [Adwords API](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/clientlibraries) (SOAP-based, still recommended for production)

Unfortunately neither API currently offers official JS client libraries.

Comment: I have a valid production developer token and I'm using the server-side Node.js client library https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client. 

Important: Is there any way to actually get the AdWords user's CCID(s) from the OAuth flow?

 I tried the Ads API but I couldn't get it to work since I couldn't find any documentation for a JS client library, however, I was able to find a Node wrapper on NPMjs.org and that's what I'm currently using: https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-adwords

Comment: If the Ads API is REST-based, then there must be some sort of endpoint for retrieving the user's CCID(s) or possibly a client for the AdWords scope that can provide me with the user's CCID programmatically. Again, I can try to switch to the Ads API (instead of the AdWords API), but is it even possible to get that data from that API?

Comment: I would imagine something like OAuth flow > refresh token > Ads API `getAccounts()` or something like that

Comment: @ihodonald, the OAuth flow won't give you the account IDs. In the Ads API, you'll need to use the `CustomerService.ListAccessibleCustomers` function for that. For the Adwords API, it's `CustomerService.getCustomers`.

Comment: Thank you so much! I knew I was just missing something!